# Adding a Back Button using react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to add a back button to my app, but I'm having some problems. The button doesn't seem to be rendering on the header. Any inputs or suggestions will be appreciated.

[image: This is what it looks like in the ios Simulator.]

```
  if (!isLoadingComplete && !props.skipLoadingScreen) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
        <NavigationContainer ref={containerRef} initialState={initialNavigationState}>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen 
            name="Home" 
            component={HamburgerMenu} 
            options={{
              headerLeft:()=>{
                <Button
                title = "Back"
                onPress={(Back)=>{ Back.goBack(); }} />
              },
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#bb1111',
              },
              headerTintColor: '#fff',
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
              },
            }}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

This is my code for the app.js.

Comment: In react-navigation 5, you don't need to override headerLeft method in order to render back button, react-navigation will do it for you

Comment: If this is only one stack screen in Navigator, then react-navigation will not render back button, because you can't go back from one screen. So make sure to add more screens to stack navigator.

Comment: @FerinPatel Hey, thanks for your help. I do have other screens in the stack navigator. I'm sorry, but can you please explain what you meant by react-navigation will do it for me. I following the docs for react-navigation.  Thanks

Comment: "react-navigation will do it for you"  this means that if you are using stack navigator and navigate to other screen, then react-navigation by default gives you back button to navigate to previous screen.